# Tiled: handling multiple map sizes

Tags: graphics, resolution, tiled

I have two sets of assets (lo res and hi res) that are exact replicas of each other except one set is twice the size of the other and used for larger screens. At runtime, I find the users screen size, and determine which set of assets to use.

I'm trying to find a way to handle this with my Tiled Maps. The maps are 40 x 23. Lo Res the tiles are 32x32. For the hi res, they are 64x64. The maps also have a few objects on them.

Is there a way I can create a 64x64 tile size map and then scale it down to 32x32 tile size? That way, I don't have to support both sizes and can instead just create the hi res map and scale it down for the lo res. Currently, I have to replicate changes to both manually.

Comment: Why is it no problem to switch between two maps at runtime, but would it be problematic to load the same map and just switch between different texture assets? This may indicate a shortcoming in the framework / library you're using.